# <p:pieChart> does not work using primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0 + Prime faces for web project.

My xhtml code is this :

```
   <p:pieChart id="sample" value="#{chartBean.pieModel}" legendPosition="w"  
                    title="Sample Pie Chart" style="width:400px;height:300px" />
```

And Java file code is this:

```
public class ChartBean implements Serializable {  

    private PieChartModel pieModel;  

    public ChartBean() {  
        createPieModel();  
    }  

    public PieChartModel getPieModel() {  
        return pieModel;  
    }  

    private void createPieModel() {  
        pieModel = new PieChartModel();  

        pieModel.set("Brand 1", 540);  
        pieModel.set("Brand 2", 325);  
        pieModel.set("Brand 3", 702);  
        pieModel.set("Brand 4", 421);  
    }  
}
```

Any while going to run this code getting this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.primefaces.component.chart.pie.PieChartRenderer.encodeData(PieChartRenderer.java:68)
    org.primefaces.component.chart.pie.PieChartRenderer.encodeScript(PieChartRenderer.java:51)
    org.primefaces.component.chart.pie.PieChartRenderer.encodeEnd(PieChartRenderer.java:36)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:45)
    org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the scope of you bean?

Comment: ManagedBean
ViewScoped       this two i used

Comment: It seems that your model is `null`. Can you verify/debug that the pie model is not null at the time the chart is created?

Comment: I forget to write managebean annotation on my class declaration.

Comment: Had exactly the same problem. Don't forget to clean your project again and again until it runs correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the model is `null`. Is you `createPieModel` method called at all? Can you verify/debug that the pie model is not null at the time the chart is created?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved the null pointer exception by importing the correct package.

I had the following

```
@Named("chartBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ChartBean implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private PieChartModel model;

    public ChartBean() 
    {
     model = new PieChartModel();
     model.set("Brand 1", 540);
     model.set("Brand 2", 325);
     model.set("Brand 3", 702);
     model.set("Brand 4", 421);
    }

    public PieChartModel getModel() 
    {
     return model;
    }
}
```

But when I Imported the package I selected wrongly javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped.
When I changed for javax.faces.view.ViewScoped, it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

XHTML page:

```
<p:pieChart id="sample" value="#{yourView.chartBean.pieModel}" legendPosition="w"  
                title="Sample Pie Chart" style="width:400px;height:300px" />
```

In your View (Just a example with lazy initialize):

```
private ChartBean chartBean;

public ChartBean getChartBean() {
    if (chartBean == null) {
    chartBean = new ChartBean();
    }
    return chartBean;
}
public void setChartBean(ChartBean chartBean) {
    this.chartBean = chartBean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this in your java bean.

```
@ManagedBean

@ViewScoped

public class ChartBean implements Serializable {  

    private PieChartModel pieModel;  

    public ChartBean() {  
        createPieModel();  
    } 
 ....
```